# MS-Access Recordset to Array, Values are transposed

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I use the following method:

```
rstArray = rs.GetRows(rs.RecordCount)
```

the output into the array is of similar size:

```
rstArray(1,6)  'just an example
```

When in reality the output (even in the query results in access) are:

```
rstArray(6,1)   'again just an example
```

My question is why does this get transposed?

And how would I reverse this? I understand if I am using late binding and working with excel I can use application.tranpose, but what about if i am just in Access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way `GetRows` works. Even if you can use Excel's transpose function, it won't always work if the number of records exceeds the maximum number of Columns in Excel.

You have 3 options:

1. Loop over the array using column-row indices instead or row-column.
2. Write a helper function that does the transposition for you.
3. Don't use `GetRows` if all you're doing is inserting the data into Excel. Use the `Range.CopyFromRecordset` method instead.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer. I currently do option #1. I am working 100% in Access for this current function, however I was well aware of copy from recordset (branching out into access from excel, woohoo?)

Comment: technically, you'd be branching out from Excel into ADO. ;-)

Comment: this might be a dumb question, but whats ADO? Is this basically the DAO vs ADDOB thing? If so I think I understand that already.

Comment: Depends on how you're using Access, and whether your `Recordset` is a `DAO.Recordset` (using `DAO` and `CurrentDB().QueryDefs`, for example) or an `ADODB.Recordset` (using `ADO` and `CurrentProject.ActiveConnection`, for example).

Comment: ADO is short for *ActiveX Data Objects*, and the ADO library, if referenced, has a project name of `ADODB`.

Comment: Not sure why you are turning it into an array. but if its to quickly paste to excel then you should lookup. CopyFromRecordset. Not sure if it works with DAO because I use ADODB but copyFromRecordset does not transpose. 

Worst case scenario you could probably use this to your advantage and use the copyFromRecordset command to output it to a sheet then use that range to do whatever you are trying to or if you're worried about speed convert that range to an array. Surely there's a quicker way though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose (rs.GetRows)`

Regards,
TheSilkCode

Comment: `Run-time error '13':  Type mismatch` will occur with this approach if the array returned from `rs.GetRows` contains any null values.